# So what information should generally be written into an "About" form?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm nearing completion of one of my kick ass programs and I'm positive it's going to be a hit.

This is just the cherry on the top (for me, nyuk nyuk). It's been a long standing tradition for me to place the about form *last* as a finishing touch.

What information should I place there for everyone to see?

Comment: I always do the about form first when I start working on the GUI, because I like the team to be credited for it's work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minimally: Icon, program name, build date, version, contact info/web page for the product.

Ideally: a secret link to several megs of easter egg fun. ;)

Comment: Why would you need a build date? Every different piece of your software released to the wild should have a *different* version number, so the build date adds nothing. And I hate Easter Eggs with a vengeance. All they do is take up more of the users resources while adding nothing to the functionality. Still, your other points are exactly what I would have answered so no downvotes for you :-)

Comment: If you don't put an easter egg at least put some witty comment :P